# react native BUILD FAILED for android

Tags: android, react-native, build

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':invertase_react-native-apple-authentication:compileDebugKotlin'.

Comment: What version of Kotlin is specified in your `build.gradle`? Might be as easy as upgrading that.

Comment: "1.6.0" do I need to update that?